# Evernote PHP API and cURL SSL connections fail

Tags: ssl, curl, evernote

I'm trying to work with the Evernote API but I'm unable to connect using SSL (specifically TLS1.2).  I'm getting an Uncaught exception in PHP and I'm unable to connect using command line cURL.

Here's the cURL dialog without specifying ciphers:

```
[root@vm13 anchors]# curl --tlsv1.2  -v
"https://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/user"  
*   Trying 216.104.243.26...  
* Connected to sandbox.evernote.com (216.104.243.26) port 443 (#0)  
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH  
* successfully set certificate verify locations:  
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt     CApath: none  
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):  
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to sandbox.evernote.com:443  
* Closing connection 0   curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to sandbox.evernote.com:443
```

I've followed EVERY article I can find regarding SSL errors and Evernote.  I've upgraded cURL, libcurl, NSS, PHP, OpenSSL, imported the sandbox.evernote.com certificate, upgraded ca certificates, etc.  Nothing has worked so far.

I'm able to connect to other SSL enabled sites just fine from the same server so I know it's not the firewall.

Comment: I finally figured it out.  My application level firewall was blocking the "everntoe" app.  I fixed the rules and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. My application level firewall was blocking the "evernote" app. I fixed the rules and now it's working